# Does nuSoap client supports WS-security headers?

Tags: php, soap, nusoap

I'm relatively new to PHP and SOAP, and I have a project to create a web-app that connects to a Web service via SOAP. The web service uses and requires WS-Security headers.

I'm currently experimenting with nuSOAP which I managed to make it work with services that do not require WS-Security headers.

My question is if nuSOAP client support inserting WS-Security headers in SOAP requests.

If not, any alternative that support WS-security headers for PHP 5?

Thanks in advance

Comment: No, it does not. Same with built in soap client. Only possible solution, we were able to found is http://wso2.org/projects/wsf/php

Comment: Thank you Uriil. With Built-in soapClient would __setSoapHeaders do the trick?

Comment: Not sure, In our project I've provided service, and my PHP collegue, told me that this library was only possible solution for him